# can not order results properly when grouping with distinct on

Tags: postgresql, grouping, postgresql-9.6

```
CREATE  TABLE test(
id integer,
content text,
number integer
)

INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(1,'a'::text, 5);
INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(2,'b'::text, 2);
INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(3,'c'::text, 2);
INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(4,'d'::text, 3);
INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(5,'e'::text, 1);
INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(6,'f'::text, 3);
INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(7,'g'::text, 3);
INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(8,'h'::text, 2);
INSERT  INTO test(id,content,number) VALUES(9,'i'::text, 4);
```

What i want is, grouping  number column and ordering results with `id` column as desc, like this;

```
| id | number
----------------
| 9  |    4
| 8  |    2
| 7  |    3
| 5  |    1
```

Here all numbers with multiple  appearance like 2,3 and 1 are grouped and seen only once and also ordered with `id` column desc.

I have tried this query but  it doesn't work for me;

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (number) number, id FROM test  ORDER  BY number,id DESC LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table:

```
SELECT id, number
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (number) number, id 
    FROM test
    ORDER BY number, id DESC
    ) s
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 4;

 id | number 
----+--------
  9 |      4
  8 |      2
  7 |      3
  5 |      1
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also:

```
select max(id) as id, number   
from test
group by number
order by id desc
limit 4
```

Comment: Just tested for curiosity. Well, without any indexes, this should better in terms of performance  if you have "many" records (for small table you don't feel difference). If use appropriate index, (something like: `... on test(number, id DESC)`) then performance will be probably almost same, for records less than 10 Million (10 mln record is just very approximately number). For more rows, this should perform better.